# node js app using a lot of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built an API for my mobile apps using NodeJs. I built this app to add contacts to my Mongo DB, but the app uses too much memory.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

module.exports = function(app, db) {
const myDb = db.db('sycontacts') 
app.post('/addcontacts', (req, res) => {
    const jason = JSON.parse(req.body.body);
    jason.forEach(function(value){

        const contact = { n: value.n, p: value.p };
        const details = { p: value.p };
        var bool = true;
        myDb.collection('contacts').find(details).toArray(function(err, item) {
        if (err) {
           res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occured' });
        } else {
            if(item.length>0){
               item.forEach(function(value){
                if(value.n == contact.n){ 
                    bool= false;
                    return;
                }
                if(!bool)return;
               });
                if(bool){
                myDb.collection('contacts').insertOne(contact, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occured' });
                        } 
                    });
                }

            }else {
                myDb.collection('contacts').insertOne(contact, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occured' });
                    } 
                });

            }

        }
    });

});
    res.send('findEd');

});
};
```

My database has about 5000000 documents.. Can anyone help me to make this app perform better and reduce its memory usage?

Comment: What does "a lot of memory" mean to you? Can you be more specific? Have you considered prebault API's like Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some error on your code and some missing optimization :

- You do async function inside forEach function, to loop wisth async function use async.eachOf or async.eachOfLimit
- You retrieve all your document in your database to insert missing documents

Do something like this instead :

```
var async = require("async");

const jason = JSON.parse(req.body.body);

// process 10 document in same time at maximum
async.eachOfLimit(jason, 10, function(value, index, callback){

    // upsert document, update all or insert if match not found
    myDb.collection('contacts').update({ n: value.n, p: value.p }, {n: value.n, p: value.p}, {multi: false, upsert: true}, function(err){

        return callback(err);

    });

}, function(err, result){

    // all is finished
    if(err)
    {
        return res.status(500).json({err: err});
    }
    else
    {
        return res.status(200).json({err: null});
    }
})
```